# How i can instantiate a new canvas intos a canvas, and set de screen space on the MainCamera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a canvas with a few GameObjects and i wanna instantiate a new GameObject that contains a canvas, so the porblem is its appears outside of main camera, and i need to set the render camera on the MainCamera of my game.

I have this and it does not work.

Main Camera where the game is running:
[img of unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI8Eq.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class newCanvas: MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
  public GameObject text; //here i put the text, that I want to appear
  private GameObject textD; //i use the for to delete the text

  public void Start(){
    textoD = Instantiate(text, transform.position, transform.rotation);//instantiate the text, and its instantiated outside of the maincamera of the game
    Invoke("DeleteText",2f);//invoke to delete the game object
  }
  
  void DeleteText(){
        Debug.Log("Delete text");
        Destroy(textD);
    }
}
```

i have something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class mainGAme : MonoBehaviour
{
public newCanvas text=null;

void Start(){
  text = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<newCanvas>();
  Instantiate(newCanvas);
}


void Update(){

}
}
```

And when i execute thegame, the object is instantiated, it is instantiated outside the maincamera as it doesn't have the render camera set to the game's maincamera.

Some know how to solvet, thank you<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the parent of your gameobject's transform to your camera's transform.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

Instantiate actually has a overload that allows you to set parent aswell

> public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

You can get your camera via static properties in Camera

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

You should check out the following docs to get a better understanding of how Transform and Gameobject are used.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html